# Is it possible to draw from 2 threads on 1 widget without additional synchronization tools?

Tags: qt, widget, qwidget

Imagine that a widget with an extension of 1000 \ 1000 pixels is conditionally vertically divided into two even parts .If I start to draw a picture in coordinates 0 \ 0 at a certain point in time in the number one thread and at the same moment in time in thread number two, I’ll start to draw another picture in the coordinates 0 \ 500 of the same widget, will this be insecure access to the same data?

Comment: I don't think it's possible with Qt, because only one thread at a time can paint on a given paint device. You cannot paint with more than one thread at a time.

Comment: I have done something like this, you could do your drawing through signals and slots that are connected using queued connections (if you don't consider this a synchronization tool). You can use those threads as in the example in [QThread description](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qthread.html#details) with a worker and a controller that has the thread instance in it.